# How to get output of ping command without Ping statistics?

Tags: windows, command, ping

For example, in Windows 7 output of command

```
ping -n 1 ::1
```

is following:

```
Pinging ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Is it possible to get output without Ping statistics (without the last four lines in this case or without two lines in case if destination host is unreachable)?

Comment: What are you using the output for?

Comment: for logging reachability of host

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe using this command:

```
ping -n 1 ::1 | find "string to search"
```

Comment: Yes! Of course! Thanks! It is better than expected: ping -n 1 ::1|find "Reply"

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer would filter out 'Request timed out' errors. Instead, use findstr /B R, which only outputs lines that start with R:

```
ping -n 1 ::1 | findstr /B R
```